# Webkit2.h, what package does it reside in?

Tags: webkit, gthumb

I'm trying to compile gThumb from source and enable all extensions, and I cannot get the webkit dependency resolved.  I've installed all of the webkit development libraries I can seem to find to no avail.

Specifically, it's looking for WebKit2/WebKit2.h.  Does anyone know what package that would be found in?

Answer (score 1):

There's [no exact match](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=webkit2.h&mode=filename&suite=quantal&arch=any), but it looks like you're looking for `libwebkitgtk-dev` as seen by the [file list](http://packages.ubuntu.com/quantal/amd64/libwebkitgtk-dev/filelist).